# Start reading from a line containing a specific string

Tags: c++, string, inputstream, seek

I'm trying to read some xyz coordinates from an input file. 
This is the input file I have:

```
input.inp

POSITIONS
1.5    2.5    1.5    C
3.2    1.5    4.5    C
1.4    4.2    3.2    C
```

I want to write a function that searches the input file for the string containing `"   C"` and then starting reading the coordinates from that line. How do I do this in c++? (I don't want to search for the the word `POSITIONS`, as that part of the input file may change later).

Comment: A variety of combinations of getline, seekg, ignore, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ifstream file("in");
string line;
while (getline(file, line)) { 
    if (line.find(" C") == string::npos)
        continue;
    istringstream ss(line);
    double x, y, z;
    ss >> x >> y >> z;
    if (!ss)
        continue; // error
    // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read all the line to `string` variable. Analyse it and if you want to read this numbers you may use `stringstream`(`<sstream>`)

```
string a = "";
in >> a;
```

//Check whether the line has C at the end or other tests and then

```
stringstream b(a, stringstream::in);

double c1=0, c2=0, c3=0;
b >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
```

Will read the numbers from that line.